# Can I calculate & print-out subtotals when using Microsoft Bot FormFlow?

Tags: c#, botframework

Here`s the point: Depending on the answers the User selected when running through a form constructed by using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.FormFlow, I would love to print out the current subtotal every now and then in the process.

I thought about using the Message() method on my FormBuilder,
but as the BuildForm() method itself is static, I`m not sure how I possibly can check the values of the already set properties.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your feedback.  There isn't a great way to do this now.  I've just added the below to the Builder library.  This should be in our next release early next week.  Would it meet your needs?

```
    #region Documentation
    /// <summary>   Given <paramref name="state"/> return a <see cref="PromptAttribute"/> with a template for the message to display. </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">    Form state type. </typeparam>
    /// <param name="state">    Form state. </param>
    /// <returns>   A PromptAttribute describing the message to display. </returns>
    #endregion
    public delegate PromptAttribute MessageDelegate<T>(T state);

IFormBuilder<T>
...
        #region Documentation
        /// <summary>   Generate a message using a delegate. </summary>
        /// <param name="generateMessage">  Delegate for building message. </param>
        /// <param name="condition">        Whether or not this step is active. </param>
        /// <returns>This form.</returns>
        #endregion
        IFormBuilder<T> Message(MessageDelegate<T> generateMessage, ConditionalDelegate<T> condition = null);
```

If you can't wait, you could use validate to update a total field in your form state and display the field value in a message.  This has the drawback though of the field being part of the user's flow.

You could also implement IField yourself and pick up from Active the last form state and generate your own prompt and recognizer.  This has the disadvantage of being more work and requiring a user response.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Can you give me a quick hint when the new version is available? Thx!